# iOS 7 status bar white and empty

Tags: ios7, uistatusbar

I'm building an iPhone app with Storyboards. But for a couple of special view controllers, I'm using just program code (which is the way I'm used to doing most of my work). For some reason, the status bar is coming up white and empty. I want do set it as the same color as the toolbar and for the status bar content to appear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know what other info would be helpful to post in order to track down the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if by "empty", you mean transparent. If so, I think the StatusBarPlugin could be useful for you:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin

It provides a very easy way to customize your status bar